# Using Google maps to calculate a 'Roundtrip'

Tags: google-maps

I'd like to be able to calculate a roundtrip in Google Maps, for e.g. running or cycling.

The idea would be to choose a distance (10km, 15km, etc) and then to calculate a few possible routes going from and returning to a set starting point

I'm having a hard time finding where I should start my search, or if this idea is even possible to implement.

Would anyone be so kind as to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

[runningmap.com](http://www.runningmap.com/beta/) is a site that I just used to calculate a round trip.  It uses Google Maps and you plot connecting points.  It adds up the distance and gives you a pretty good idea of how far you went.

Comment: That URL is 404 not found